# trailing whitespace. patch does not apply

Tags: git

I have 3 files `a\test.txt`, `b\test.txt` and `c\test.txt`:

`a\test.txt` :

```
x
y
z
```

`b\test.txt` :

```
x
z
p
q
```

`c\test.txt` :

```
x
y
```

Now I created a patch between a and b:

```
git diff --no-prefix --binary a b > mypatch.patch
```

Resulting in this patch:

```
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 1b2c8f8..e0b3aec 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 x
-y
-z
\ No newline at end of file
+z
+p
+q
\ No newline at end of file
```

Next I want to apply mypatch.patch on `c\test.txt`:

```
cd c:\
git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace ../mypatch.patch
```

I get the error:

```
../mypatch.patch:10: trailing whitespace.
z
../mypatch.patch:11: trailing whitespace.
p
error: patch failed: test.txt:1
error: test.txt: patch does not apply
```

I have read a bunch of post here on SO but have still not managed to get it applied any ideas?

I don't see any trailing spaces in mypatch.patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the patch does not apply is not related to the trailing whitespace.

The patch tries to remove the `y` and `z` lines, but `z` does not exist in the file you're trying to apply it to (`c/text.txt`).

Something like the following would apply :

```
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 66455a1..1a0d96d 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
 x
-y
\ No newline at end of file
+z
+p
+q
\ No newline at end of file
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try `patch -p1 < filename.patch`.

BTW, a similar question here: [My diff contains trailing whitespace - how to get rid of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509950/my-diff-contains-trailing-whitespace-how-to-get-rid-of-it)