# Not able to ignore white space related changes in Git

Tags: git, github

In order to commit only non-whitespace related changes, I tried doing this:

```
git diff -w --no-color | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

But I am getting this error:

```
<stdin>:12: indent with spaces.
        if ( ! $data['first_name'] && ! $data['last_name']) {
<stdin>:13: indent with spaces.
            $data['first_name']   = NULL;
<stdin>:14: indent with spaces.
            $data['last_name'] = NULL;
<stdin>:15: indent with spaces.
        }
error: patch failed: application/libraries/api_data.php:89
error: application/libraries/api_data.php: patch does not apply
```

I have also set `autocrlf` to `false` like this:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

And yet, with `git diff` I see the whole file as changed instead of the lines I have added.

Also my output of `git config -l`:

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
core.pager=less
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit
alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
alias.spull=svn rebase
alias.spush=svn dcommit
alias.alias=!git config --list | grep 'alias\.' | sed 's/alias\.\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1\     => \2/' | sort
include.path=~/.gitcinclude
include.path=.githubconfig
include.path=.gitcredential
diff.exif.textconv=exif
credential.helper=osxkeychain
core.excludesfile=/Users/ankurk/.gitignore_global
core.autocrlf=false
core.whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=opendiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
user.name=
user.email=
commit.template=/Users/ankurk/.stCommitMsg
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
core.autocrlf=false
remote.origin.url=
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.feature_add-eds-brand-name-marketers.remote=origin
branch.feature_add-eds-brand-name-marketers.merge=refs/heads/feature_repo
```

What I can do to fix this?

Comment: can you share your "git config -l" output?

Comment: consider removing personal data from your edit...also I posted a possible answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [My diff contains trailing whitespace - how to get rid of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509950/my-diff-contains-trailing-whitespace-how-to-get-rid-of-it), and looking at your output, I'm not sure those are errors due to whitespaces.  I think those are warnings.

I think the real error is line 89 :

> error: patch failed: application/libraries/api_data.php:89
>   error: application/libraries/api_data.php: patch does not apply

What is on line 89 there?

Comment: Line 89 just has a closing brace for a function.

Comment: consider using git apply with --whitespace=nowarn to verify if those are errors or warnings.

regarding the closing brace, is there any reason it can't be applied?

Comment: Still patch failed. :/

Comment: I am not telling you that that command would make the patch succeed, I am trying to narrow down the problem

Comment: I can't think of any reason why the patch wouldn't work on that line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770177/git-patch-does-not-apply this might be interesting to you